# Obtaining a list of x,y coordinates of a specific RGB value from a screenshot of the screen

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, rgb

I have been trying to take a screenshot of my screen and find every x,y coordinate of a specific color.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np

image = ImageGrab.grab()
indices = np.all(image == (209, 219, 221), axis=-1)
print(indices)
print(zip(indices[0], indices[1]))
```

When I run my code, I receive one coordinate and then an error message.

```
(1126, 555)
[1126, 555]
False

    print(zip(indices[0], indices[1]))
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

How come it isn't working? The color is on-screen.

Comment: Are you sure there is more than one pixel with specified RGB? The error has nothing to do with it being single. You are treating `indices` (trying to access `indices[0]`) as list whereas it is a boolean scalar.

Comment: You probably want your own solution wrapped inside `np.where()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're making an error with the following line:

```
indices = np.all(image == (209, 219, 221), axis=-1)
```

You can iterate over the pixels directly and achieve the result you want:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np

image = ImageGrab.grab()

color = (43, 43, 43)
indices = []

width, height = image.size

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        if image.getpixel((x, y)) == color:
            indices.append((x, y))

print(indices)
```